# Test mousedown event

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react code which is drag and resize of the height of div and it works perfectly fine and clickable div is resizer I need to write a unit test to test event listeners are called or not

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mousePosition;
    retriveAgentHistoryHeight();
    const panel = dragableElement?.current as HTMLElement;
    const resizerEle = resizer?.current as HTMLElement;

    const setPanelHeight = dx => {
      const newHeight = `${parseInt(getComputedStyle(panel, '').height) + dx}px`;
      panel.style.height = newHeight;
      saveAgentHistoryHeight(newHeight);
    };

    const resize = e => {
      const dx = mousePosition - e.y;
      mousePosition = e.y;
      setPanelHeight(dx);
    };

    const touchResizeEvent = e => {
      const y = parseInt(e.touches[0].clientY);
      const dx = mousePosition - y;
      mousePosition = y;
      setPanelHeight(dx);
    };

    const mouseOnPressEvent = e => {
      mousePosition = e.y;
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', resize, false);
      setResizeClass('active');
      panel.style.userSelect = 'none';
    };

    const screenTouchEvent = e => {
      mousePosition = parseInt(e.touches[0].clientY);
      document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchResizeEvent);
      setResizeClass('active');
      panel.style.userSelect = 'none';
    };

    const mouseOnReleaseEvent = () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize, false);
      setResizeClass('');
      panel.style.userSelect = 'auto';
    };

    const screenTouchEndEvent = () => {
      document.removeEventListener('touchmove', touchResizeEvent);
      setResizeClass('');
      panel.style.userSelect = 'auto';
    };

    if (resizerEle) {
      resizerEle.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseOnPressEvent);
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseOnReleaseEvent);
      resizerEle.addEventListener('touchstart', screenTouchEvent);
      document.addEventListener('touchend', screenTouchEndEvent);
    }

    return () => {
      if (resizerEle) {
        resizerEle.removeEventListener('mousedown', mouseOnPressEvent);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseOnReleaseEvent);
        resizerEle.removeEventListener('touchstart', screenTouchEvent);
        document.removeEventListener('touchend', screenTouchEndEvent);
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

my test.js

```
 it('should load verify load event of resizer on mouse release', async () => {
        const {getByTestId } = render(<ContactHistoryHandledByAgent />);
        const mouseOnPressEvent = jest.fn(a => a);
        fireEvent.mouseUp(getByTestId('agent-history-resizer'));
        expect(mouseOnPressEvent).toBeCalled();
    })
```

expect(mouseOnPressEvent).toBeCalled(); is not working

I wanted to check event such as mouseOnPressEvent is called or not

Comment: Could you please include some more info? From where are you getting the `resizer` instance ?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `jest.fn()` to a constant and pass it as the event parameter to your Component. Then you specify with the `simulate(event)` method the event which will happen during the test. And at the end you check if it was called.

Here an example for a onClick test:

```
 const onclick = jest.fn();
 const component = render(<ContactHistoryHandledByAgent onClick={onclick} />);
 component.simulate("click");
 expect(onclick).toHaveBeenCalled();
```